# COMO FAZER CALCULO DE PORCENTAGEM COM MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 ID  tiposang 
 1     A+
 2     A-
 3     B+
 4     O-
```

Boa noite ,estou fazendo um projeto e em meu banco de dados tenho um tabela parecida com esta acima , eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para realizar uma consulta que mostre a porcentagem que cada tipo de sangue presente em meu BD e que cada porcentagem desta seja salva em uma certa variável para ser utilizada em um código php

Answer (score 0):

Para começar, você precisaria criar uma consulta PHP que lhe mostre a quantidade de registros da tabela.

Criei um exemplo muito simples de como você pode fazer, utilizando 3 consultas para você entender melhor.

Suponho que sua tabela se chame `tb_tipo_sanguinho`

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'sangue';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);


$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tb_tipo_sanguino')->fetch_array();

$A_positivo = $mysqli->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS APOSITIVO FROM tb_user WHERE tiposang = "A+"')->fetch_array();
$A_negativo = $mysqli->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS ANEGATIVO FROM tb_user WHERE tiposang = "A-"')->fetch_array();

$total      = $result['total'];
$A_positivo = $A_positivo['APOSITIVO'];
$A_negativo = $A_negativo['ANEGATIVO'];

echo '<pre>';
print_r('A+: '.$A_positivo); print_r(' ('.porcentagem_nx($A_positivo, $total).'%)');
echo '<pre>';
print_r('A-: '.$A_negativo); print_r(' ('.porcentagem_nx($A_negativo, $total).'%)');
echo '<pre>';
print_r('TOTAL: '.$total);

function porcentagem_nx ( $parcial, $total ) {
    return ( $parcial * 100 ) / $total;
}
```